# WebView getting 404 on a good url

Tags: android, webview

I'm getting a 404 in a webview using the following code . . .

```
    LocateBrowser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.locatebrowser);
LocateBrowser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
LocateBrowser.loadUrl("http://maps.google.com/maps?z=17&t=h&q=loc:31.8526,-110.9959");
```

If I copy that url into a browser on my PC, it works just fine.

If I don't implement the WebViewClient (the second line), the browser on the Android device opens up and displays the map properly.  But I don't want it to do that, I want it to show in my WebView.  The map looks like this in the external browser...
[image: Map in external browser]

The problem is the above code first displays the screen above without the map and an indeterminate progress "Loading . . ." symbol for about a second and then displays google's 404 page saying "the URL /Search was not found on this server".

Is there something else I need to do?
Thanks,
Gary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I failed to enable java script.  Following code works but it produces a screen real estate problem.

```
    LocateBrowser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.locatebrowser);
LocateBrowser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
WebSettings webSettings = LocateBrowser.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
LocateBrowser.loadUrl("http://maps.google.com/maps?z=17&t=h&q=loc:31.8526,-110.9959");
```

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong to use the WebViewClient ? If it works with that solution without using a the map api, that would be ok.

What is you aim ?